# How can I subtract datetimes to give the results in the format I require?

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan, hour

I'm trying to subtract between two dateTimes in a way that I'll see all totaled hours.(including mm and ss if theres any)
for Example:

```
TimeSpan j = DateTime.Parse("06/05/2015 12:00:00").Subtract(DateTime.Parse("04/05/2015 14:00:00"));
```

I want to return a string that contains "46:00:00"

```
TimeSpan j = DateTime.Parse("06/05/2015 12:00:00").Subtract(DateTime.Parse("05/05/2015 12:00:00"));
```

I want to return a string that contains "24:00:00"

```
TimeSpan j = DateTime.Parse("06/05/2015 12:00:00").Subtract(DateTime.Parse("05/05/2015 18:00:00"));
```

I want to return a string that contains "18:00:00"

Answer (score 4):

You can use  `TimeSpan.TotalHours` and `String.Format`:

```
string result = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", (int)j.TotalHours, j.Minutes, j.Seconds);
```

The cast to `int` is needed to remove the fractional part from the `TotalHours`.

The `D2` ensures that you always get two digits like `00` even if the minute part is `0`.

MSDN: [The "D" (or decimal) format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#DFormatString)

Comment: If this is your prefered answer, then click the tick to mark it so.

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this,

I have done only for your first condition

```
 DateTime d1 = Convert.ToDateTime( "06/05/2015 12:00:00");
 DateTime d2 = Convert.ToDateTime( "04/05/2015 14:00:00");
 TimeSpan j = d1 - d2;
 string ti = (j.TotalHours + " : " + j.TotalMinutes + " : " + j.TotalSeconds).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

i have done something like:

```
TimeSpan j = DateTime.Parse("06/05/2015 12:00:00").Subtract(DateTime.Parse("04/05/2015 14:00:00"));
int i = 0;
if(j.Days >= 1)
{
    i = j.Days * 24;
    i = i + j.Hours;
}
string s = String.Concat(i.ToString(), ":", j.Minutes.ToString(), ":", j.Seconds.ToString());
```